# Advantages of different methods for bypassing RTTI

Tags: c++, rtti

Suppose i want a program that can manage different animals using a Base-Class/Interface `Animal`. The animals can have specific behavior (Fly/Climb/ThrowPoo). The goal is to iterate over a `list<Animal*>` and perform some action with them using their specific behavior.

The first thing that comes to mind is just casting the `Animal*`s using `dynamic_cast` or `static_cast` + `typeid`. But that approach is hard to maintain and can become quite slow if i have a bigger amount of objects to iterate over.

After some research i found the following ways to avoid RTTI and use virtual function calls instead:

1. Declare every method an animal could possibly have as a virtual method in the `Animal` class.
2. Use a dynamic-dispatch pattern, like the visitor pattern.

In my opinion both of these approaches have their own flaws. The first one pollutes the animal class and it's derived classes with a lot of abundant code/utility and you will need some methods like `bool canFly()` if you want to avoid specific function calls (If the function guarantees some behavior on call for example). I like the second approach a lot, but it is nowhere near as easy to read and understand as the previous one.

Can you elaborate the advantages/disadvantages of casting (RTTI), virtual functions and dynamic-dispatch patterns and when to properly use them? Also if i missed any methods or strategies please include them in the comparison.

Comment: This may be way too broad for SO. However, if a good answer does come along, it will be awesome.

Comment: Why not have a pure-virtual `virtual void perform_specific_action() = 0` in the interface, and the derived class implements it: `struct Bird : Animal { void perform_specific_action() override { fly(); croak(); } };`?

Comment: @KerrekSB I would like to upvote that answer, but what I was looking for were general guidelines on how to deal with Polymorphism/Type Information. I thought about the exact same when writing the question, but it is only good if you are dealing with a small amout of specific actions.

Comment: @LucaFülbier: I don't think this is a real goal. There doesn't seem to be a well-thought out problem here. You don't generally need to "avoid polymorphism" if polymorphism describes the problem you're modelling. You just have to find the right design for your solution, and polymorphism will probably be part of it. I cannot see in your question a real, well-posed problem that needs solving. There are traditional, well-known trade-offs for multimethods (add functions vs add classes), and known fast look-up techniques (e.g. logarithmic), but each is specific to some problem.

Comment: As stated in the question i did not want to avoid Polymorphism, but RTTI to access polymorphic elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that when you're thinking about `dynamic_cast`, you're envisioning the `makeYourSound(Animal* a)` function as consisting of two hundred `if...else if` blocks, each one testing for and handling a particular type of animal. Yeah, that's slow and unmaintainable. Don't do it.

What `dynamic_cast` is good for, really, is *optional interfaces*. A particular thing that some animals can do, but not others. `if(Eagle* e = dynamic_cast<Eagle*>(a))` is a code smell, and a bad one. `if(IFly* f = dynamic_cast<IFly*>(a))` smells much less. It avoids code duplication, it avoids polluting the base class with meaningless methods and tap-dancing around how to handle non-flying animals, and it describes more precisely in your code *what you are trying to do*.

The advantage of virtual function-based polymorphism is that the object is fully in charge, something that appeals greatly to OO purists. But in some cases, as a practial programmer, you don't *want* the object to be in control, just to tell your code a bit more about itself so it can be properly dealt with. More nuanced guidelines, like the OCP, are more widely applicable, and they don't rule out `dynamic_cast`, just indiscriminate use of it.

Comment: I read something like your second paragraph in Item 39 of Effective C++. A really nice approach utilizing the best of dynamic_cast and virtual functions, I will keep this one in mind!

Comment: John Lakos calls your second paragraph the "protocol hierarchy" design pattern, in which `IFly` would be an example of a protocol class.